# MySQLi query with date range criteria

Tags: mysql, date-range

The following code works well so far for searching on multiple fields. How can I include a date rage criteria in it to search with (startdate, enddate)?

The date field is named "IncidentDate" in the table "t_persons"

```
$criteria = array('FamilyName', 'FirstName', 'OtherNames', 'NRCNo', 'PassportNo', 'Gender', 'IncidenceCountryID', 'Status', 'OffenceKeyword', 'AgencyID', 'CountryID', 'IncidenceCountryID' );
    $likes = "";
    $url_criteria = '';
    foreach ( $criteria AS $criterion ) {
            if ( ! empty($_POST[$criterion]) ) {
                    $value = ($_POST[$criterion]);
                    $likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
                    $url_criteria .= '&amp;'.$criterion.'='.htmlentities($_POST[$criterion]);
            } elseif ( ! empty($_GET[$criterion]) ) {
                    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[$criterion]);
                    $likes .= " AND `$criterion` LIKE '%$value%'";
                    $url_criteria .= '&amp;'.$criterion.'='.htmlentities($_GET[$criterion]);
            } //var_dump($likes);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_persons WHERE PersonID>0" . $likes . " ORDER BY PersonID DESC";
```

Comment: FYI, if you want to allow both `GET` and `POST`, you can use `$_REQUEST` -- it contains parameters from both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['start_date']) && !empty($_REQUEST['end_date'])) {
    $start = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['start_date']);
    $end = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['end_date']);
    $likes .= " AND IncidentDate BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
    $url_criteria .= '&amp;start_date='.htmlentities($_REQUEST['start_date']).'&amp;end_date='.htmlentities($_REQUEST['end_date']);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt response. I will try just that. Stay well.